# Issue with a Traceback error in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, typeerror

I'm new to programming with python (for class) and just can't seem to figure this one out. Here is my code:

```
department = raw_input
salesQuarterOneThisYear = input
salesQuarterTwoThisYear = input
salesQuarterThreeThisYear = input
salesQuarterFourThisYear = input
salesQuarterOneLastYear = input
salesQuarterTwoLastYear = input
salesQuarterThreeLastYear = input
salesQuarterFourLastYear = input
QUIT = 'ZZZZ'
print 'Enter department name or', QUIT,'to quit:'
raw_input('')

while department != QUIT:
    print 'Enter sales for first quarter this year:'
    salesQuarter1ThisYear = input('')
    print 'Enter sales for second quarter this year:'
    salesQuarter2ThisYear = input('')
    print 'Enter sales for third quarter this year:'
    salesQuarter3ThisYear = input('')
    print 'Enter sales for fourth quarter this year:'
    salesQuarter4ThisYear = input('')
    print 'Enter sales for first quarter last year:'
    salesQuarter1LastYear = input('')
    print 'Enter sales for second quarter last year'
    salesQuarter2LastYear = input('')
    print 'Enter sales for third quarter last year:'
    salesQuarter3LastYear = input('')
    print 'Enter sales for fourth quarter last year:'
    salesQuarter4LastYear = input
    total_this_year = salesQuarterOneThisYear + salesQuarterTwoThisYear + salesQuarterThreeThisYear + salesQuarterFourThisYear
    total_last_year = salesQuarterOneLastYear + salesQuarterTwoLastYear + salesQuarterThreeLastYear + salesQuarterFourLastYear
    print 'Total this year = ',total_this_year
    print 'Total last year = ',total_last_year
    if total_this_year is total_last_year:
        print 'Status = Same'
    if total_this_year > total_last_year:
        print 'Status = Higher'
    if total_this_year < total_last_year:
        print 'Status = Lower'

    print

    print 'Department: ',department
    if total_this_year is total_last_year:
        print 'Status = Same'
    if total_this_year > total_last_year:
        print 'Status = Higher'
    if total_this_year < total_last_year:
        print 'Status = Lower'

    print 'Enter department name or', QUIT,'to quit:'
    raw_input('')
```

The error I receive is this:

```
  File ..., line 31, in <module>
    total_this_year = salesQuarterOneThisYear + salesQuarterTwoThisYear + salesQuarterThreeThisYear + salesQuarterFourThisYear
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'builtin_function_or_method'
```

Can you please help me with what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Since you're using python 2.7, I wouldn't use `input()` for this, since it evaluates arbitrary code. [Example](http://paste.pound-python.org/show/oGdJf1fOOrjHiUmet5NR/). Instead, use `int(raw_input(...))`, `float(raw_input(...))`, `str(raw_input(...))`, etc

Comment: Thanks Kevin! Question, what are the differences between input(), int(raw_input(...)), float(raw_input(...)), & str(raw_input(...))

Comment: Think of `input()` as taking a line of code from the user and evaluating it, much like the python console. Basically anything that you can put after a `some_variable = ` in python is acceptable. `raw_input()` gives you the raw string that the user entered. `int()` will convert that to an integer if it can (otherwise it'll raise a `ValueError`), and `float()` will convert the string to a floating-point number (read: a number with a decimal point). I'm not sure why I included `str()` in there now, since that'l just convert the string ... to a string.

Comment: If you want just the raw string (like if you're looking for a name or something), use `name_or_whatever = raw_input('What is thy name?')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never called `input` for quarter four:

```
salesQuarter4LastYear = input
```

That assigns the *function object*, not a string. Call the function instead:

```
salesQuarter4LastYear = input()
```